# I felt like I don't have any future

Tags: interviewing, communication, salary, hiring-process

I am already 32 years old. I worked as a cashier for 3 yrs, 10 yrs ago. After I gave birth, I decided to stay at home to focus with my child. I am single parent by the way. Fortunately, I found an online job and worked there for 6 yrs. But recently, the company started a different path and have no work for us remote workers. Now, I've been unemployed for 3 months. I feel like I am stuck with my life. My former classmates are now successful on their career and here I am failing. I am planning to apply in a BPO but I don't have the courage to do so. It was 10 years ago since the last time I've been in an interview. I'm afraid to get rejected. But I really need a job. Can you tell me something to cheer me up? Thank you.

Comment: Getting rejected is nothing to be afraid of, it happens to everyone

Comment: I've been rejected from almost every job application I've made, and I've made thousands.  Its normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have 4 kids. Although, I  am a male, I regard them as my greatest achievement. And so should you.

If you need a job, then I am sure you will find the courage. There is absolutely nothing wrong with a few rejections. If you do get them  use them as an opportunity to improve. Ask the interviewers, what you did wrong.

Comment: I really need a job and I want to give my child the future she deserves.   Thank you. I'll find that courage and take a step forward. Before this month ends, I am claiming I will be employed.

Comment: Hi. Finally I tried to apply yesterday, and I got the job offer. My training will start on the 6th of October. 

Answer (score 3):

Success isn't measured by other peoples careers.

Apply for jobs and feed your child, life is about the journey, fear of rejection just holds you back. And there is nothing to be afraid of.

Comment: I have those sleepless nights thinking about everything. Feels pressured and depressed at the same time. thank you. I will get that courage to start again

Comment: Hi. Finally I tried to apply yesterday, and I got the job offer. My training will start on the 6th of October. 

Comment: Thats excellent, best wishes for your child and work

Comment: Thank you.  Your words helped me a lot. May God bless you always.